# Convert 24 Hour values into HHMMSS - Time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time

How do I convert integer hour type values like `1700`, `2400`, `1000` into timestamps `17:00:00`, `00:00:00`, `10:00:00`?

```
import time
hour = int(1700)
print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(hour)))
Out[1]: '00:28'
```

or

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Hour':[1700, 2400, 1000]})
print(time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(data.Hour)))

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Comment: The values in your `Hour` column are integers, not strings. Try converting them to `str` before converting them to time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the integer hour to a string which you can parse and format using `datetime.strptime` and `datetime.strftime` respectively.

**Demo:**

```
from datetime import datetime

x = 1700
dt = datetime.strptime(str(x), '%H%M')
formatted_str = datetime.strftime(dt, '%H:%M:%S')
print(formatted_str)
```

**Output:**

```
17:00:00
```